# How can I paint CEdit Control without uncovered area?

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I have CDialg and CEdit Control on dialog. So, to paint CEdit control without sub-classing CEdit Class, I used `CDialog::OnCtlColor` like this.

```
if( nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT )
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(200, 255, 200));
}
```

But as you can see, that it omits some margin area of edit control.

How can I paint it whole window Rect of CEdit?

[image]

Comment: Damn~ This site is so harsh at newbies. :p I Cant even post a picture?

Comment: too many newbie trolls posting inappropriate material (remember, this is a site often visited while at work).

Comment: I understand that Michael. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to return a brush with the correct colour, so create a brush in the dialog constructor

```
#define EDITCOLOR RGB(200, 255, 200)
m_brEdit.CreateSolidBrush(EDITCOLOR);
```

and in the `OnCtlColor()` function,

```
HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)
{   pDC->SetBkColor(EDITCOLOR);
    hbr = m_brEdit;
}
return hbr;
```

Comment: That works like a dream. Thanks Edward. I was trying to paint Edit control via FillSolidRect() on dialogs paint function. ::GetDc() to get DC of edit control and paint it. But this is much simple and elegant. Thanks.