# Chaning the background color of SysLink Control - MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am having problem in setting the background color of a SysLink Control.

I have a group box and also couple of SysLink Controls. When I change the back color of group box and also the syslink control, this is what it looks like...

[image]

**A small white color line appears at the end.** It doesn't go even after adjusting the width of the control.

Here is my code:

```
HBRUSH PanelDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 255));//RGB(223, 233, 247)
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

and OnPaint...

```
void PanelDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CRect rect1;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_MENU_GROUP_BOX)->GetWindowRect(&rect1);
    ScreenToClient(&rect1);
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rect1, RGB(0, 0, 255));// RGB(223, 233, 247)); //247
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();
}
```

Comment: By using CPaintDC you are validating the dialog's invalid region, then CDialogEx::OnPaint does not get the proper invalidated region. Try using CClientDC instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `OnPaint()` handler, try returning a brush with the same background color in `OnCtlColor()`, like in [my SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687484/1850797) to a similar question.